# Attribute translation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, attributes, translation

So the issue I've encountered days ago still makes me unconfortable with my code. I can't get proper translation for my application: Yml looks like that:

```
 pl:
   errors: &errors
   format: ! '%{attribute} %{message}'
   messages: 
      confirmation: nie zgadza się z potwierdzeniem

   activemodel:
     errors: 
       <<: *errors
   activerecord:
     errors:
       <<: *errors
```

And model looks like that:

```
 module Account
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessor: password_confirmation
   end
 end
```

And flash in controller declared:

```
 flash[:errors] = @user.errors.full_messages
```

I tried and read activerecord documentation and stack previous questions ([How to use Rails I18n.t to translate an ActiveRecord attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863526/how-to-use-rails-i18n-t-to-translate-an-activerecord-attribute), [Translated attributes in Rails error messages (Rails 2.3.2, I18N)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898754/translated-attributes-in-rails-error-messages-rails-2-3-2-i18n)). Yet it still doesn't work as I wanted.
password_confirmation remains "Password Confirmation", and not "Potwierdzenie hasła" as it shoul be. The screenshot might explain it better: http://i42.tinypic.com/1glz5.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your User model is in a namespace, thus you have to declare the namespace in your translation file also. Try the following to get the correct translation for password_confirmation:

```
pl:    
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      account/user:
        password_confirmation: "Potwierdzenie hasła"
```